# The mathematical model of integrated marketing communications

Tags: mathematical-economics, marketing

I am trying to generalize the media buying problem, the first steps are to use media buying approach to several advertising channels at once. But there should be next steps as well. Are there works that try to model the entire ICM? ICM planning at the enterprise level for one or several product groups. Google and Google scholar give none. Maybe such endeavours exists but under different names (terms)?

There is lot of literature under terms "mathematical model of marketing mix".

Comment: This question could be improved and made of more general interest by linking to or defining the terms used.